# Does this binary recursive sorting algorithm have a name?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Today I was trying to come up with a sorting algorithm and code it for practice. The one I decided on works like this. The algorithm first picks the zeroth element (let's call this the pivot) and iterates through the list. If an element is smaller than the pivot, then it is moved to somewhere on the list left to the pivot. After it finishes parsing through the list, it splits the list into two lists: the list to the left of the pivot and the list to the right of the pivot, and then recursively repeats the task on each side.

I tried looking through common comparison sorting algorithms in Wikipedia; I found methods such as quick sort, selection sort, and insertion sort, but none of these seem to be the one I'm looking for. My code is in C++, and I'll leave it here below if you want to take a look at it.

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void sort(vector<T>& vec){
  int size = vec.size();
  if (size <= 1){ //this is the most basic case
    return;
  }

  T pivot = vec[0];
  int index = 0; //to help split the list later
  for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i){ //moving (or not moving) the elements
    if (vec[i] < pivot){
      vec.insert(vec.begin(), vec[i]);
      vec.erase(vec.begin() + i + 1);
      ++index;
    }
  }

  if (index == 0){ //in case the 0th element is the smallest
    vec.erase(vec.begin());
    sort(vec);
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), pivot);
  }
  else if(index == size - 1){ //in case the 0th element is the largest
    vec.pop_back();
    sort(vec);
    vec.push_back(pivot);
  }

  //here is the main recursive portion
  vector<T> left = vector<T>(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + index);
  sort(left);
  vector<T> right = vector<T>(vec.begin() + index + 1, vec.end());
  sort(right);

  //concatenating the sorted lists together
  left.push_back(pivot);
  left.insert(left.end(), right.begin(), right.end());

  vec = left;
}
```

example of it in action:

```
int main() {
  int arr[] = {-2, 5, 3, 1, 0, 12, -2, 5, 120, 0, 12, -100};
  vector<int> vec = vector<int>(arr, arr + 12);

  cout << "input: \n";

  print(vec);

  sort(vec);

  cout << "\nafter sorting: \n";

  print(vec);

  return 0;
}
```

result:

```
input:
-2 5 3 1 0 12 -2 5 120 0 12 -100

after sorting:
-100 -2 -2 0 0 1 3 5 5 12 12 120
```

Comment: It's an inferior version of Quicksort, with lots of extra copy steps.

Comment: It's probably ~kwiksoRt~

Comment: `insert` and `erase` are hiding a lot of behind-the-scenes effort, moving the latter portions of the vector back and forth.

Comment: Yeah I figured it's an inefficient version of quick sort. I was just wondering if it had a name.

Comment: This uses a shift-insert, followed by a delete-shift to relocate values strictly less than the pivot selection. This is inefficient, and markedly different than traditional quicksort that *swaps* the current prospect to an ascending index location, that ultimately becomes the final resting place of the pivot value. In traditional quicksort there is no sequence shifting like there is here, where both the insert and delete operations cause. Where did you say you got this algorithm?

Comment: I just wanted to code a recursive sorting algorithm for practice and this was the first one that came to my mind. After coding it I was wondering if this had a name (maybe if it did I'd be able to read about it and find out the specific inefficient parts, etc.).

Comment: Inefficient algorithms don't tend to earn names, as they don't tend to be widely used or taught. With perhaps the notable exception of [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Comment: This might be better used for a linked list, where insertion time complexity is O(1), but [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) should be faster.